# How to add an extra attribute for %discount when getting products? In MongoDB, NodeJs, Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I am new to NodeJs, Mongoose, MongoDB.

I have this collection of products:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6300db81604458b99283a79b"),
    "name": "Product",
    "mrp": "200",
    "yourPrice": 152,
    "fromVendor": "62f156491b7a7c055f7c580e",
    "stock": 99,
    "sku": "KT86T2F2V5",
    "totalSold": 1,
    "status": "active",
    "images": [],
    "createdAt": ISODate("2022-08-20T13:02:57.013Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2022-08-20T13:02:57.013Z"),
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6300dbb7604458b99283a79d"),
    "name": "Product1",
    "mrp": "2000",
    "yourPrice": 1500,
    "fromVendor": "62f156491b7a7c055f7c580e",
    "stock": 4,
    "sku": "XXSNRDI48V",
    "totalSold": 0,
    "status": "draft",
    "images": [],
    "createdAt": ISODate("2022-08-20T13:03:51.212Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2022-08-20T13:03:51.212Z"),
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

So for this collection, I need to find the products whose stock is greater than 0, and whose status is active. After finding those products I need to add an attribute as discount where it will calculate the discount with respect to the mrp(Market price or the Maximum retail price) attribute and yourPrice(A price at which the vendor is selling the product) attribute.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how to achieve this with the aggregation pipeline and some standard operators:
( I assumed "discount" is the difference between those 2 fields )

I will mention that there are edge cases to consider, for example can "yourPrice" be higher than "mrp"? if so what is the behaviour you want there? currently it will show a negative discount.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      status: "active",
      stock: {
        $gt: 0
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      discount: {
        "$multiply": [
          {
            $divide: [
              {
                $subtract: [
                  {
                    $toInt: "$mrp"
                  },
                  "$yourPrice"
                ]
              },
              {
                $toInt: "$mrp"
              }
            ]
          },
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oKzq3KoszrN)

Comment: Thank You for the answer. But, the calculation for the discount will be like: ((mrp-yourPrice)/mrp)*100.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect it, the approach is still the same - you just need to use additional math operators like `$divide` and `$multiply`. I recommend for next time if there is a specific output you require you add it to the question body.